# Redirect all http to https, all www to non-www, and remove .html from all urls

Tags: .htaccess, http, url, redirect, https

- .html should be removed from the end of every URL
- All http links should go to https
- All www links should go to non-www

How do I achieve this with .htaccess, and will this be sufficient for Google to crawl my site correctly and not produce duplicate links?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

# remove .html from all files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

# redirect all http to https and all www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This seems to have done the job. Several answers I found online failed - http://www.example.com was often incorrectly directed to https://www.example.com.